# Fragment throws nullpointer

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I have a `fragment` which is in a `navigation bar`.
When i am in the fragment just before the "activity_spar" `fragment`, it starts loading the `fragment` itself.
However it throws me an `nullpointer exception` which i cannot traceback.

It says on `line 180`, which has this code:

```
my_layout.addView(cb,params);
```

running through the `debugger` showed that my params are not null and my cb isn't either.
Can anyone explain how to trace this back?

```
06-17 19:38:21.431: E/AndroidRuntime(25923): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-17 19:38:21.431: E/AndroidRuntime(25923): Process: info.androidhive.jsonparsen, PID: 25923
06-17 19:38:21.431: E/AndroidRuntime(25923): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-17 19:38:21.431: E/AndroidRuntime(25923):    at info.androidhive.jsonparsen.activity_Spar$downloadJsonitems.onPostExecute(activity_Spar.java:180)
06-17 19:38:21.431: E/AndroidRuntime(25923):    at info.androidhive.jsonparsen.activity_Spar$downloadJsonitems.onPostExecute(activity_Spar.java:1)
06-17 19:38:21.431: E/AndroidRuntime(25923):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
06-17 19:38:21.431: E/AndroidRuntime(25923):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
06-17 19:38:21.431: E/AndroidRuntime(25923):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
06-17 19:38:21.431: E/AndroidRuntime(25923):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-17 19:38:21.431: E/AndroidRuntime(25923):    at     android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-17 19:38:21.431: E/AndroidRuntime(25923):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
06-17 19:38:21.431: E/AndroidRuntime(25923):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-17 19:38:21.431: E/AndroidRuntime(25923):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-17 19:38:21.431: E/AndroidRuntime(25923):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
06-17 19:38:21.431: E/AndroidRuntime(25923):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:606)
06-17 19:38:21.431: E/AndroidRuntime(25923):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)


//AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
LinearLayout my_layout = (LinearLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.sparstoretest); 
    LinearLayout my_checked_layout = (LinearLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.sparstorechecked);
    LinearLayout ImageView = (LinearLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.sparstoresettings);
    LinearLayout ImageView2 = (LinearLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.sparstoresettings2);

@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,  ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.topMargin=2;

        for (int n = 0; n < listitems.size(); n++) {
            CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(getActivity());

            cb.setId(Integer.parseInt(listitems.get(n).get("cbid")));
            cb.setText(listitems.get(n).get("product"));
            cb.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            ImageView image = new ImageView(getActivity());
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_discard);
            image.setId(Integer.parseInt(listitems.get(n).get("cbid")));
            image.setLayoutParams(params);
            image.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(final View v) {
                    showpopup(v.getId());
                }
            });
            Log.i("activity spar", "storename" + storename);
            if (listitems.get(n).get("state").toString().equals("1") && listitems.get(n).get("store").toString().equals(storename)) {
                cb.setChecked(true);
                my_checked_layout.addView(cb,params);
                cb.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(255, 184, 239, 220));
                cb.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255, 255, 255));
                image.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(184,239,220));

                ImageView2.addView(image);
            } else if (listitems.get(n).get("store").toString().equals(storename)){
                cb.setChecked(false);
                cb.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(255, 19, 202, 140));
                cb.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255, 255, 255));
                my_layout.addView(cb,params);
                image.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(19,202,140));
                ImageView.addView(image);
            }
```

Comment: Did you call this before OnResume?  my_layout could be null.

Comment: My_layout is set in the same class as the onPreExecute where this code is in

Comment: We need a little bit more code, because you're **sure** that nothing is null, then how can we guess where the problem is? Something is clearly null, you just can't see it (or it's happening inside some code you have no control), but with a single line of code, we can't really tell :)

Comment: @MartínMarconcini i added some code, i don't know if its the right part, but i think thats the most relevant part.

Comment: found it, i was inflating an View but didn't set the right Layout to the id's i was trying to pull

Comment: Glad you found the answer, see how providing enough code helps? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your sparstoretest layout defined in that activity? You are getting nullpointer because my_layout object is NULL. Check you are inflating the correct layout and sparstoretest is defined in that activity/fragment xml.

Comment: The last part was right. 
I inflated the wrong Layout so my sparstoretest wasn't defined in that layout. If you could change your answer with this: return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_store_spar,container,false);  i can set it as answered.

Comment: I changed it so it makes sense with the code provided. (There's no way for me to guess the name of your fragment class) @user3749616